# Creating New columns in data Frame using R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data frame given below;

```
NPA_Jan Risk_Jan NAP_Feb Risk_Feb
Yes     High     No      Medium
No       Low      No      Low
No       High     Yes     High
Yes      High     Yes     High
Yes      Low      No      Low
```

I am expecting an output below:

```
NPA_Jan_New   Risk_Jan_New NPA_Feb_New Risk_Feb_New
1             1            0              0
0             0            0              0
0             1            1              1
1             1            1              1
1             0            0              0
```

Wherever there is NPA is 'Yes' and Risk as 'High' there should tag 1.

Comment: `(df == "Yes" | df == "High") + 0`

Comment: I am not looking at combinations. Those are the four independent columns

Comment: You can use `df[,grep('^NPA', colnames(df))]` to distinguish `NPA` column

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is as David said,

```
df.new <- as.data.frame((df == "Yes" | df == "High") + 0)
colnames(df.new) <- paste(colnames(df.new), '_new', sep='')
```

Comment: Or `df[paste0(names(df), '_new')] <- (df == "Yes" | df == "High") + 0`

Comment: Yes if appended

Answer (score 1):

An option is using

```
out <- +(sapply(df, `%in%`, c("Yes", "High")))
colnames(out) <- paste0(colnames(df), "_new")
out
#     NPA_Jan_new Risk_Jan_new NAP_Feb_new Risk_Feb_new
#[1,]           1            1           0            0
#[2,]           0            0           0            0
#[3,]           0            1           1            1
#[4,]           1            1           1            1
#[5,]           1            0           0            0
```